# Update Database with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I am trying to update information in my database with Laravel. Not sure what I am doing wrong but I can't seem to find where the problem is. Here is the code for my edit page (This is the page where I would edit information taken from my DB).

```
{{ Form::open(['url'=>'portfolio/update']) }}
    <div>
        {{ Form::label('portfolio_title', 'Portfolio Title:') }}
        {{ Form::text('portfolio_title',$work->portfolio_title) }}
        {{ $errors->first('portfolio_title','<span class="error">:message</span>') }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ Form::label('portfolio_description', 'Portfolio Description') }}<br>
        {{ Form::textarea('portfolio_description', $work->portfolio_description, ['size' => '50x5']) }}
        {{ $errors->first('portfolio_description','<span class="error">:message</span>') }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ Form::label('portfolio_content', 'Portfolio Content') }}<br>
        {{ Form::textarea('portfolio_content', $work->portfolio_content, ['size' => '50x5']) }}
        {{ $errors->first('portfolio_content','<span class="error">:message</span>') }}
    </div>
    {{ Form::hidden('id',$work->id) }}
    <div>
        {{ Form::submit('Update Work') }}
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I have a controller called PortfolioController that will save info to database and what not.

```
public function edit($work_title){
    $work = Portfolio::wherePortfolio_title($work_title)->first();
    return View::make('portfolio/edit', ['work' => $work]);
}

public function update(){
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $input = Input::except('id');

    if( !$this->portfolio->fill($input)->isValid()){
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->portfolio->errors);
    }

    $work = Portfolio::find($id);

    $work->portfolio_title = Input::get('id');

    $work->save();

}
```

Here is my route that I am working with:

```
Route::resource('portfolio','PortfolioController');
Route::post('portfolio/update','PortfolioController@update');
```

I am able to get the form populated with the correct information but when i change something like the title and click update, the page reloads but does not save in the DB. Sometimes I will get an `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error. This has been pretty frustrating for me so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding a call to dd function to check if the update method is really getting called. Ex: dd('PortfolioController@update');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just actually use your resource route?

First, remove the `portfolio/update` route. You don't need it.

Then change your `Form::open` to this:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['portfolio.update', $work->portfolio_title], 'method' => 'put']) }}
```

This way you target the update method in your RESTful controller.

Finally change that to use the `portfolio_title` as identifier and you should be able to remove the hidden `id` field from your form.

```
public function update($work_title){}
```

Please take a look at:

- [RESTful controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)
- [Opening a form](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form)

Comment: I was using my resource route but I kept getting the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error. I thought it was because I was using the wrong method, that is why I had `Route::post()`; I made the changes you suggested and i recived no errors but the Database does not update, just reloads the page with the changes I made.

Comment: I think that's because you don't actually update your model with the input. Try either assigning it manually, property by property or use `$work->fill($input)` to assign all values. However then you need to specify the attributes in a `$fillables` array. More info about [mass assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: I have already set up my `$fillables` array with what can be mass assigned. I created a method in my model called `updateRecord($id,$wTitle,$wDescription,$wContent)`  Then i use the static `find` method to find the record using its ID `$work = Portfolio::find($id);`. Then I go property by property assigning the values `$work->portfolio_title = $wTitle;` then save it `$work->save();` Nothing saves in the DB just reloads the page again.

Comment: What happens if you put `dd('test')` inside your update method?

Comment: Nothing, the page just reloads again with the updates.

Comment: Strange. Do you really have the form opening like the one in my answer?

Comment: Yes I do, even copied it and paste it in my editor to double check. Here is what the browser sees when the page is loaded `<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/laravel_test/portfolio/public/portfolio/R%26R%20Woodcrafts" accept-charset="UTF-8">``<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">`

Comment: Ok this looks perfect. And when you submit the form the URL you see is actually `http://localhost/laravel_test/portfolio/public/portfolio/R%26R%20Woodcra‌​fts` and you still get your form?

Comment: After I make some changes and click update this is my URL `http://localhost/laravel_test/portfolio/public/portfolio/R&R%20Woodcrafts/edit` And yes i still get my form with no updates to my DB

Comment: Strange. That looks like you're getting redirected back. Is it possible that your validator fails?

Comment: It's possible but if I leave an input empty I get the correct errors. The problem may be in my edit method in my Controller. Also if i change the form open to {{ Form::open(['route' => [**'portfolio/update'**, $work->portfolio_title], 'method' => 'put']) }} I get an errors saying `Route [portfolio/update] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_test\portfolio\app\views\portfolio\edit.blade.php) `

Comment: Can you comment out the validation part? Just to be sure it's not that

Comment: It was in fact the validation that was returning it back to the edit page. I'll have to take a look into that and figure out why. Now I am having a problem when i pass my variables with the information from the edit form to the updateRecord method, all variables are empty. Gotta love bugs..

Comment: If you need help with that please add the code to your question.

Comment: In my controller in the update method I have this line `$this->portfolio->updateRecord($input);` Should pass all values from the form. When i get to my Model, in the updateRecord($input) method I return the $input but see absolutely nothing just a blank page. If i return the $input variable in the controller I see all the values.

Comment: You can't just return it from your method to see it. Try `print_r($input)` `var_dump($input)` or `dd($input)`

Comment: Makes sense. I did dd() function and it showed what I wanted.